# Why does dialler sometimes fail to dial?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app, motorola-moto-g2

I recently bought a Moto G2, with Android 4.4.4.  I'm very happy with it, other than the fact that sometimes when I dial a number, the phone just drops the call immediately, and doesn't even save it in the recently dialed list.  I tried installing a 3rd party dialer, and found exactly the same behavior.  What's up with that?  How to fix it?

Also, there doesn't seem to be any way to get to your speed dials/favorite contacts except by making and ending a call.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Izzy - done.  Nothing fancy on this phone; I bought it on Amazon.com and haven't done anything more invasive than install apps from Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Though I'm not able to help you on this issue, the additional details provided should help others doing so. Good luck!